# 404 Error: unable to serve static react build with django rest framework, unless I go to /index.html

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-react

I have a React front end that I turned into static files. I used `npm run build` to make the folder. Then I configured my Django Rest Framework:

settings.py

```
FRONTEND_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'frontend', 'build'))
```

urls.py

```
re_path(r'^(?P<path>.*)$', serve, { 'document_root': settings.FRONTEND_ROOT }),
```

when I got to the `localhost:8000`, I get a 404 page. If howerver, i got to `localhost:8000/index.html`, then I dont get a 404 but the react app. The css and html are not loaded though.

Is this a proper way to connect the static react to my django backend? Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django `serve` is rather for serving static files in development: [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/views/#django.views.static.serve).

For development, I just run react dev server in one terminal and django dev server in the second terminal.

For productions you have few options to serve static files:

- take a look at [WhiteNoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/) for serving static files in django (I had example somewhere how I config it, but cant find it right now, please let me know if you will need),
- upload static react files to S3 and serve with CDN (in the case of AWS deployment and large traffic)
- if you would like to keep everything in one machine, then I would recommend docker-compose. It is nice solution because you can serve react with nginx. What is more, you can use docker-compose to renew SSL certificate from Let's Encrypt. This is the option that I'm using. Below my docker-compose.

I'm working on a complete tutorial on how to build your own SaaS application with [Django and React from scratch](https://saasitive.com/tutorial/django-react-boilerplate-saas/). The docker-compose is from tutorial.

```
# docker-compose
version: '2'

services:
    nginx: 
        restart: unless-stopped
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./docker/nginx/Dockerfile
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        volumes:
            - static_volume:/app/backend/server/django_static
            - ./docker/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - ./docker/nginx/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
            - ./docker/nginx/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
        depends_on: 
            - backend
    certbot:
        image: certbot/certbot
        restart: unless-stopped
        volumes:
            - ./docker/nginx/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
            - ./docker/nginx/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
        entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"       
    backend:
        restart: unless-stopped
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./docker/backend/Dockerfile
        volumes:
            
        entrypoint: /app/docker/backend/wsgi-entrypoint.sh
        volumes:
            - .:/app
            - static_volume:/app/backend/server/django_static
        ports:
            - 8003:8003
        expose:
            - 8003        

volumes:
    static_volume: {}
```

The nginx dockerfile is in two steps:

1. Build react
2. Start nginx

```
# nginx dockerfile
# build environment
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine as build

ADD ./frontend /app/frontend/
WORKDIR /app/frontend
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/frontend/build /usr/share/nginx/html
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

`default.conf` file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name yourdomain.com;
    server_tokens off;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name yourdomain.com;
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    client_max_body_size 20M;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api {
        try_files $uri @proxy_api;
    }

    location @proxy_api {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass   http://backend:8003;
    }

    location /django_static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /app/backend/server/django_static/;
    }
}
```

dockerfile for django

```
FROM python:3.8.3-alpine

WORKDIR /app
ADD ./backend/requirements.txt /app/backend/


RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install gunicorn
RUN pip install -r backend/requirements.txt

ADD ./backend /app/backend
ADD ./docker /app/docker

RUN rm -f /app/backend/server/db.sqlite3
```

`wsgi-entrypoint.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

#ls -al /app/backend/server/static/client/static/js

until cd /app/backend/server
do
    echo "Waiting for server volume..."
done

until ./manage.py migrate
do
    echo "Waiting for db to be ready..."
    sleep 2
done

ls /app/backend/server

./manage.py collectstatic --noinput

gunicorn server.wsgi --bind 0.0.0.0:8003 --workers 4 --threads 4
#./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8003
```

`init-letsencrypt.sh` script from https://medium.com/@pentacent/nginx-and-lets-encrypt-with-docker-in-less-than-5-minutes-b4b8a60d3a71 I highly recommend this article!

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! [ -x "$(command -v docker-compose)" ]; then
  echo 'Error: docker-compose is not installed.' >&2
  exit 1
fi

domains=(yourdomain.com www.yourdomain.com)
rsa_key_size=4096
data_path="./docker/nginx/certbot"
email="" # Adding a valid address is strongly recommended
staging=0 # Set to 1 if you're testing your setup to avoid hitting request limits

if [ -d "$data_path" ]; then
  read -p "Existing data found for $domains. Continue and replace existing certificate? (y/N) " decision
  if [ "$decision" != "Y" ] && [ "$decision" != "y" ]; then
    exit
  fi
fi


if [ ! -e "$data_path/conf/options-ssl-nginx.conf" ] || [ ! -e "$data_path/conf/ssl-dhparams.pem" ]; then
  echo "### Downloading recommended TLS parameters ..."
  mkdir -p "$data_path/conf"
  curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/certbot/certbot/master/certbot-nginx/certbot_nginx/_internal/tls_configs/options-ssl-nginx.conf > "$data_path/conf/options-ssl-nginx.conf"
  curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/certbot/certbot/master/certbot/certbot/ssl-dhparams.pem > "$data_path/conf/ssl-dhparams.pem"
  echo
fi

echo "### Creating dummy certificate for $domains ..."
path="/etc/letsencrypt/live/$domains"
mkdir -p "$data_path/conf/live/$domains"
docker-compose run --rm --entrypoint "\
  openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:1024 -days 1\
    -keyout '$path/privkey.pem' \
    -out '$path/fullchain.pem' \
    -subj '/CN=localhost'" certbot
echo


echo "### Starting nginx ..."
docker-compose up --force-recreate -d nginx
echo

echo "### Deleting dummy certificate for $domains ..."
docker-compose run --rm --entrypoint "\
  rm -Rf /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domains && \
  rm -Rf /etc/letsencrypt/archive/$domains && \
  rm -Rf /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/$domains.conf" certbot
echo


echo "### Requesting Let's Encrypt certificate for $domains ..."
#Join $domains to -d args
domain_args=""
for domain in "${domains[@]}"; do
  domain_args="$domain_args -d $domain"
done

# Select appropriate email arg
case "$email" in
  "") email_arg="--register-unsafely-without-email" ;;
  *) email_arg="--email $email" ;;
esac

# Enable staging mode if needed
if [ $staging != "0" ]; then staging_arg="--staging"; fi

docker-compose run --rm --entrypoint "\
  certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/certbot \
    $staging_arg \
    $email_arg \
    $domain_args \
    --rsa-key-size $rsa_key_size \
    --agree-tos \
    --force-renewal" certbot
echo

echo "### Reloading nginx ..."
docker-compose exec nginx nginx -s reload
```

I pasted here the files from the tutorial, so you would need to change the directory structure to yours and the domain (sorry!). I'm still working on the tutorial. If you have any questions, I'm happy to help.

Comment: hey, since your tutorial is not out yet, i tried to follow the in another repo and got an error where when I refresh the page, I get a 404.